# Google Compute Engine VM instance error in google.startup.script

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Upon rebooting the Google Compute Engine VM instance, I see these errors:

```
startupscript: Finished running startup script /var/run/google.startup.script

xxxx accounts-from-metadata: WARNING error while trying to update accounts: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>

xxxx accounts-from-metadata: WARNING error while trying to update accounts: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you change the network settings or firewall rules prior to rebooting the VM? Can you still SSH into this instance? Does it have the ability to reach other instances or the network?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Upon viewing the original question and reformatting it, it looks like there's a network error at bootup (was hidden due to the text in `<...>` being treated as HTML and not viewable), so my earlier answer (below) may not be applicable. Leaving it here for future reference.

Please check your network settings, firewalls, etc. in the meantime.

---

**Original text:**

You may have a syntax error in the [`sshKeys` metadata key](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata#default). The format is:

```
<username>:<protocol> <key-blob> <username@example.com>
```

The right hand side of the `:` is essentially the contents of your public key, e.g., `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub`.

To see your current metadata key:

1. ssh into the instance, e.g., via [`gcloud compute ssh`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh), or via the SSH button in Developers Console
2. Load this key via:

   ```
   curl http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/sshKeys \
        -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
   ```

   and check the formatting.

You can then [change the metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata) on your instance.